# How to include Zxing library to android project?

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing, qr-code

I have read some answer for this question in stackoverflow, but it is not working for me. I have already a project, and now I want to integrate QR Code and barcode reader into my project.

I downloaded the zip file from: [core-2.2.zip](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list)

I didn't find any "core.jar", I read that I have to integrate files added in "core" folder. Do I have to add all classes to my project (the whole folder)? or do I have to create a jar file with that folder?

I am using Android Studio. Any one can help me? thank you

Comment: you need to make that jar

Answer (score 5):

There is indeed an Android application that is part of the ZXing project.
It uses the **core** module released in maven central. If you have a maven project (which is unlikely for most Android applications) you can add the following dependency to your ***pom.xml*** file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

for a *Gradle* project:

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
```

or you can directly download the compiled .jar from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.0/core-3.2.0.jar).

*Please, notice that this answer refers to version 3.2.0 which is the latest stable one. Version 2.2 could be similarly obtained.*

Comment: As of 02/2017, 3.3.0 ist current: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.3.0/core-3.3.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

For QRCode reading you can also use Google Play service 7.8 and beyond. You may check this [link from Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to include a jar, you can not be downloaded. At first when you try to take zxing had the same problem, luckily I found the jar and I could download it. You have to verify either version which you need.

[core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/2.3.0)

I have not worked in Android Studio, this is in eclipse but I imagine it must be the same way.

[image: eclipse]

What you need to add it is the full project zxing to your project as a library to the main project. Activity and create a layout that include this library.

[image: library]

Which is also the default is:

```
public class Validador extends CaptureActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.validador);
}
```

}

Layout :

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center">
    <include layout="@layout/capture"/>
</FrameLayout>
```