# Zxing barcode locally (no need to ask user to install a 3rd party app) without using intent, red line in the middle screen missing

Tags: android, zxing

after carefully following this answer: [How to integrate Zxing Barcode Scanner without installing the actual zxing app (cannot resolve symbol: .android.CaptureActivity)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159104/how-to-integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-without-installing-the-actual-zxing-app) by Liran Cohen

the scanner should not be opened in a separate activity (called via intent),
it should be shown just below a button (like logout).

I was able to detect/scan and get the decoded string of the barcode but the problem is the red line is missing, how to make the red line appear?

I extended the captureActivity to a activity I am using like readerActivity and override the handleDecode function to detect/scan and decode the qr image.

just want to know how to show the red line.

also tried changing the following code in the viewfinderview but still not working:

```
 int middle = frame.width() /2 + frame.left;
```

under the onDraw() function

also tried calling the function:

```
 viewfinderView.setWillNotDraw(false);
```

in the oncreate function of the captureActivity, the red line is still hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the code of Zxing on [GitHub](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) and add it to your project.

Look at these activity [CaptureActivity](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java) for adding similar code to your activity.